# Не работает create_user django

Tags: django, регистрация

### Не работает create_user и в редакторе тоже не высвечивается

from django.shortcuts import redirect, render

from django.contrib.auth.models import User , UserManager

def register(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    first_name= request.POST['first_name']
    last_name= request.POST['last_name']
    username= request.POST['username']
    email= request.POST['email']
    password1= request.POST['password1']
    password2= request.POST['password2']
    user = User.objects.create_user(first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name,username=username,email=email,password=password1)
    user.save()
    print('usercrated')
    return redirect('')

else:
    return render(request,'register.html' )
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раз уж никто не отвечает, сделайте это "ленивым способом", вот код:

```js
if request.method == 'POST':
    user = User() # Создаем объект класса User
    user.first_name= request.POST['first_name']
    user.last_name= request.POST['last_name']
    user.username= request.POST['username']
    user.email= request.POST['email']
    user.password1= request.POST['password1']
    user.password2= request.POST['password2']
    user.save()
    print('usercrated')
    return redirect('')

else:
    return render(request,'register.html' )
```

**Обратите внимание!**

Этот метод называется "ленивым", потому что на самом деле создается всего один запрос в СУБД (система управления базой данных). Django умная штука. И этот запрос создается, только когда Вы вызываете метод `save()`. Конечно тот способ тоже можно использовать, но в данном случае этот код легче читается

Comment: Спасибо все заработало

Comment: Тогда можете отметить вопрос верным, нажав на галочку